# how to generate xml with element and attribute using xml explicit

Tags: sql, for-xml-explicit

im trying to generate xml in the following format:

```
<Root>
    <Domain>Abc</Domain>
    <Name>Xyz</Name>
    <Contents>
        <Content>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <Value>Test 1</Value>
            <Record ID="1">Test 1</Record>
        </Content>
        <Content>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <Value>Test 2</Value>
            <Record ID="2">Test 2</Record>
        </Content>
    </Contents>
</Root>
```

My query is as follows:

```
declare @TestTable table (ID int, Value varchar(100))

insert into @TestTable values (1,'Test 1')
insert into @TestTable values (2,'Test 2')

declare @Domain varchar(max)='Abc'
declare @Name varchar(max)='Xyz'

SELECT
1 AS Tag,
NULL AS Parent,
@Domain as 'Root!1!Domain!Element',
@Name as 'Root!1!Name!Element',
NULL as 'Contents!2!Element',
NULL as 'Content!3!ID!Element',
NULL as 'Content!3!Value!Element',
NULL as 'Content!3!Record!Element'

union

SELECT
2 AS Tag,
1 AS Parent,
NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL

union

select
3 as Tag,
2 as Parent,
NUll,NUll,NULL,
ID,Value,Value
from @TestTable

FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

my query does not produce the record tag completely, currently it is

```
<Record>Test 2</Record>
```

which should be as

```
<Record ID=2>Test 2</Record>
```

I tried all the possibilities but not getting the tag. Can anyone help me solving this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the expected output from xml explicit, instead i used xml path and got the output. this is my updated query

```
SELECT 
       @Domain "Domain",
       @Name "Name",
(
SELECT 
       ID  "ID",
       Value   "Value",
       (select 
        ID "@ID",
        Value  as "text()"      
        FOR XML PATH('Record'), ELEMENTS, TYPE )       
FROM   @TestTable
FOR XML PATH ('Content'), TYPE, ROOT('Contents')
)
FOR XML PATH ('Root')
```

you are welcome to post the fix which uses xml explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the ORDER BY when use FOR XML EXPLICIT.

---

```
SELECT
    1 AS Tag,
    NULL AS Parent,
    @Domain as 'Root!1!Domain!Element',
    @Name as 'Root!1!Name!Element',
    NULL as 'Contents!2!Element',
    NULL as 'Content!3!ID!Element',
    NULL as 'Content!3!Value!Element',
    NULL as 'Record!4!ID',
    NULL as 'Record!4!'

union

SELECT
    2 AS Tag,
    1 AS Parent,
    @Domain,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL, null

union

select
    3 as Tag,
    2 as Parent,
    @Domain,NUll,NULL,
    ID,Value,null,null

    from @TestTable
union

select
    4 as Tag,
    3 as Parent,
    @Domain,NUll,NULL,
    ID,Value,ID,Value

    from @TestTable
ORDER BY    'Root!1!Domain!Element','Contents!2!Element','Content!3!ID!Element','Record!4!ID'

FOR XML EXPLICIT
```